# How do I convert string into integers in this dictionary then loop through it?

Tags: python

How do I convert string into integers in this dictionary then loop through it without getting errors like *invalid literal for int() with base 10* :(

```
mydict = {('6.0', '1.0'): '345.2', ('3.0', '9.0'): '632.7',
    ('2.0', '3.0'): '222.4', ('1.0', '4.0'): '672.1', ('8.0', '6.0'): '822.6',
    ('3.0', '8.0'): '225.5', ('7.0', '7.0'): '534.0', ('4.0', '7.0'): '599.3',
    ('8.0', '9.0'): '273.5', ('5.0', '3.0'): '822.5', ('4.0', '2.0'): '326.6'}
```

in which `(key1, key2): value`

I would also like to loop through this dictionary, and calculate using this formula...

```
((key1 * 360 / key2 * 180) + value)
```

for each key pair. Then, I would print out the 3 largest value resulted from the calculation. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but we won't write all of the code for you. You need to show you've tried to do it yourself. Next time , include your actual `dict` in your question, and you won't have to ask a follow up -- all of the strings in the keys in your original post contained `int`s, not `float`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
res = map(lambda x: (float(x[0][0]) * 360.) / (float(x[0][1]) * 180.) + float(x[1]), mydict.items())
```

That will produce something like :

```
[357.2, 633.37]
```

To get the 3 largest:

```
sorted(res, reverse=True)[0:3]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Convert twice.

```
>>> int('1.0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.0'
>>> int(float('1.0'))
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following implementation

```
>>> calc_list=(int(float(a))*360/int(float(b))*180+int(float(v)) 
    for (a,b),v in mydict.iteritems())
>>> print '\n'.join(map(str,heapq.nlargest(3,calc_list)))
389145
129926
108822
>>>
```